# Mongoose Can't Connect Without Internet

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have my MongoDB server running on `localhost:27017`, and while I can usually run my Node.js app fine, when I disconnect from the internet Mongoose throws the error

```
Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]
```

Note that I can still connect to the MongoDB server from the Mongo shell client. Also, if I start up my app first and then lose internet connection, my app can access the database fine offline. So why can't it start up without internet?

EDIT: here is the error in full

```
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]
    at null.<anonymous> (<My App>\node_modules\mongoose\
node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\server.js:555:74)
    at emit (events.js:118:17)
    at null.<anonymous> (<My App>\node_modules\mongoose\
node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\connection_pool.js:156:15)
    at emit (events.js:110:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (<My App>\node_modules\mongoos
e\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\connection.js:534:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at net.js:923:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Edit: wording

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: When you say "disconnect the internet" do you mean unplug the cable or are you shutting down the NIC at the OS level?

Comment: As in disconnect from all wifi networks

Comment: @PeterVC For extra measure, I also added a note at the bottom about another error I get just in case it's relevant

Comment: Could it be the IP that node is binding to?  Have you tried forcing node to bind to 127.0.0.1?

Comment: huh, I changed the mongoose connection url from `localhost:27017` to `127.0.0.1:27017` and now everything works, even offline. Thanks, if you post it as an answer I'll gladly accept it. Though any idea why 127.0.0.1 works but localhost doesn't?

Comment: Can you please post your server side script..?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.  By turning off your wifi interface the OS is no longer able to resolve localhost.

Comment: Just wondering, why would mongoose not be able to resolve localhost while offline if my browser can?

Comment: I suspect your using Windows?  This may help [explain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997442/nodejs-cannot-resolve-localhost-on-windows).

Comment: Hi all, I've an offline laptop, not connected to any router.
I didn't have IP address so I've used Windows Loopback Adapter. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc708322(v=ws.10).aspx

but when I run mongo.exe I get Failed to connect 127.0.0.1.
how can I configure mongo.exe if the process is not runing at all?

Answer (score 0):

Consider [node-offline-localhost](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-offline-localhost).

Add the following before the breaking code:

```
require('node-offline-localhost').always();
```

And it just works (hopefully), at least until [RFC 3493](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3493.txt) gets [fixed](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/QA/Networking/NameResolution/ADDRCONFIG).

Full disclosure: I authored this package to streamline https in my dev environment when offline.