# Does using a proxy to run both react and express app on same port prevents preflight requests?

Tags: reactjs, express, port, preflight

I saw the question [Is it possible to run Node and React in the same port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67254140/is-it-possible-to-run-node-and-react-in-the-same-port)

It's answer says we need to use proxy to do this.

But I don't understand, does this will make the ports same?

does this prevent preflight OPTIONS requests?