# mongoose connection failed with localhost while offline

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, localhost

I am facing a issue while connecting to Mongodb using mongoose.
The problem is when i am offline it shows connection failed to localhost:27017
but when i am online it connects successfully.
The code for reference is below:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/database');
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', function (err) {
console.log('connection error', err);
});
db.once('open', function () {
console.log('connected.');
});
```

And here is the screenshot of both the situation.
[image: first command fails when there was no internet and second one connects successfully]

Do I need to make some configuration in my system to make it work or It just work this way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongoose Can't Connect Without Internet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29178484/mongoose-cant-connect-without-internet)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a duplicate of [Mongoose Can't Connect Without Internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29178484/mongoose-cant-connect-without-internet)

Anyhow, just replace `localhost` with `127.0.0.1` in the connection string. The issue lies within Windows, see [nodejs cannot resolve 'localhost' on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997442/nodejs-cannot-resolve-localhost-on-windows)

Comment: Thanks . Its showing you can't accept answer in 4 mins.

Comment: Don't worry about it, but in the future you should thoroughly research your issue before submitting a question. I literally just googled your question and got that duplicate as first result, you could easily have done the same.

Comment: I did it but I have not able to phrase it properly.